# How to pass all attributes passed to my custom directive to the control used inside directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can someone help me with this problem?

Let's say I have a custom directive called mycontrol. I want to pass all the attributes in this directive to a control used inside my directive template. Here is an example -

```
<mycontrol data-var1="value1" data-var2="value2"..../>
```

My template is - `<input/>`

How do I define the directive definition object to get the output as

```
<input data-var1="value1" data-var2="value2"...>
```

Please note that the attributes number and names are not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

All of the attributes should be carried over.

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XgA6T/

Open the console and look at the element that is logged.

The directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(elem);
            var domElem = elem[0];
            if (domElem.dataset && domElem.dataset != null) {
                console.log(domElem.dataset);
                scope.values = domElem.dataset;
            }
        }
    }; 
});
```

Comment: replace:true did the trick.. Thank you aet. It works great if I have just one element in the template. But my template is something like this - '<div><span/><input/></div>'. using replace:true would transfer all the attrs to div tag. How do I transfer them to input?